# setting up multiple redirects on one page using PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to set up multiple redirects on a single page and I found an example online on how to accomplish this. However, I need some help in setting this up on my server. The link to the online example is here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=208962.0

In the example, the OP asks to have a generic links page such as www.mysite.com/links/index.php, which is where all the redirects would occur.

So if I were to visit the following link: www.mysite.com/links/affiliate1, then I would be redirected to affiliate1.com. If I typed www.mysite.com/links/affiliate2, then I would be redirected to its respective page, affiliate2.com, and so on.

My question is this: on my server, how do I set this up? In my root directory of, say, www.mysite.com, I have a index.php page under the "links" sub-directory with the following code:

```
                <?php
                $affiliates = array('affiliate1' => 'http://www.example.com',
                                          'affiliate2' => 'http://www.something.com',
                                          'affiliate3' => 'http://www.bored.com');
                foreach ($affiliates as $affiliate => $link) {
                    if ($affiliate == $_GET['link']) {
                            header("Location: $link");
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

But if I now type http://mysite.com/links/affiliate1, I won't be directed to affiliate1.com. Instead, I'm going to end up with a "Not Found" page (The requested URL /links/affiliate1 was not found on this server). How do I set this up correctly?

Comment: Are you using .htaccess with mod_rewrite ? I asked that because with this you can accomplish what you want.

Comment: Shouldn't you use http://mysite.com/links/?link=affiliate1 instead ?

Comment: haha... @yent. That works. Could you please post your response as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.